# Pandas: plot line and bar plot in the same figure _with custom index_

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am looking to plot a line and bar charts on in pandas on the same plot.
The usual way of doing it seems to share the `ax` variable with the different plots, e.g.

```
fake_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(21, 6)), columns=list('ABCDEF'))
other_fake_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(21, 6)), columns=list('ABCDEF')) / 10
ax = fake_data.plot(kind='line', figsize=(10, 5))
other_fake_data.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, secondary_y=True)
```

[image]

This works as expected. However, if I have a *custom* index in the two data frame, the second plot seems to cover the first one:

```
fake_index = range(100, 121)
fake_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(21, 6)), columns=list('ABCDEF'))
fake_data.index = fake_index
other_fake_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(21, 6)), columns=list('ABCDEF')) / 10
other_fake_data.index = fake_index
ax = fake_data.plot(kind='line', figsize=(10, 5), alpha=.8)
other_fake_data.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, secondary_y=True, alpha=.3)
```

[image]

Is there a way of preventing plotting both of them using the custom index?

Comment: The tick locations of the barplot are integer indexed, beginning at 0. When the line plot index corresponds to the tick index, then the plot works. In the second plot, the tick label is 100, but the tick index is 0. Presumably, the lineplot index for that point, is 100, not 0, so the plot doesn't work.

Comment: not sure if I follow. In the latter case the index are also integers and they are shared by both df

Comment: The tick locations on the plot are not the same as the indices of the dataframe.

Comment: oh I see thanks. Is there a way of aligning them? or to plot as the first example, but replace the tick with custom ones?

Comment: `ax = fake_data.reset_index(drop=True).plot(kind='line', figsize=(10, 5), alpha=.8)`

Comment: I think that would just use `0, 1, ...` as the tick? I want to use `100, 101, ...`