# How to print 2 plots at the same image using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, charts, finance

I have a dataset of sold cars like this (by model):

model, year, price

Ford Focus, 2006, 5000

Ford Focus, 2000, 1500

I'd like to calculate several statistics ant plot them at the same image:

1. average offer price by year
2. year to year loose
3. number of offers by year

I'm using pandas library to count statistics:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#csv format
# model, year, price
# Ford Focus, 2004, 5000
cars = pd.read_csv(path)
focuses = cars[lambda x: x["model"] == "Ford Focus"]
avg_prices = focuses.groupby("year").mean()
offers_count = focuses.groupby("year").count()["price"]

avg_prices.plot()
offers_count.plot.bar(rot=0)

plt.title("Ford Focus")

plt.show()
```

But I have to images instead of one.

How to combine statistics to one image where plots has the same x axis (like stock charts)?

[image]

Comment: Does [How to plot multiple lines in one figure in Pandas Python based on data from multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40071096/8239061) answer your question?

Comment: @SecretAgentMan no, because plots has different kinds. first one is the line and second one is the bar

Comment: Does [How can I recreate this plot of a pandas DataFrame, line and bar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63666509/8239061) answer your question?

Comment: Possibly related:  [How to plot a line over a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62987103/8239061) | [Pandas: plot line and bar plot in the same figure _with custom index_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63125109/8239061)

Comment: @SecretAgentMan added image to clear what kind of plot I'd like to have

Comment: Related:  candlesticks:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6272093/8239061

Comment: A quick Google search found [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-stock-analysis-candlestick-chart-with-python-and-plotly-e619143642bb) complete with code.  One of the top results...

Comment: @SecretAgentMan the issue to plot 2 statistics of different dimensions. I cannot show the price and count using the same axis. Financial charts has the same x axis but different y axis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224373/discussion-between-alex-klimashevsky-and-secretagentman).